# Text color change only for one word in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I want to change the color of the text as show below:

```
text: "Hello World"
```

"Hello" should change to "blue" and
"World" should change to "red" color.

Also i dont want to use below given format (because I am reading colors from cpp):

```
Text {
    text: "<font color=\"#0000FF\">Hello</font> <font color=\"#FF0000\">World</font>"
}
```

Is there any other way to change the color for only one word (in qml)?

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to use `Flow` and multiple `Text` elements.

```
Flow {
    Text {
        text: "Hello"
        color: "#0000FF"
    }
    Text {
        text: " "
    }
    Text {
        text: "World"
        color: "#FF0000"
    }
}
```

> Also i dont want to use below given format (because I am reading colors from cpp):
>
> ```
> Text {
>    text: "<font color=\"#0000FF\">Hello</font> <font color=\"#FF0000\">World</font>"
> }
> ```

What's stopping you from doing the following ?

```
text: `<font color="${cppObject.helloColor}">Hello</font> <font color="${cppObject.worldColor}">World</font>`
```

This uses [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) but you can also do it with normal string concatenation.